# Issues with BitmapFactory.decodeFile when i pick a picture

Tags: android, android-studio

When i pick a picture the BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null.
Here is my function:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Here we need to check if the activity that was triggers was the Image Gallery.
    // If it is the requestCode will match the LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS value.
    // If the resultCode is RESULT_OK and there is some data we know that an image was picked.
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        // Let's read picked image data - its URI
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath,options);
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        // Do something with the bitmap


        // At the end remember to close the cursor or you will end with the RuntimeException!
        cursor.close();
    }

}
```

Can somebody tell me what is the issue?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are trying to achive

Comment: I try to pick a picture from the gallery and get it's bitmap

Answer (score 0):

`String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));`

do you have the filePath in the variable **imagePath**  ? or is imagePath value is null too ?

 **UPDATE** 

your  **BitmapFactory.decodeFile()**  is returning null because may be the imageSize is too big and its throwing some exception. 
check your log and see if there is any  **outOfMemory Bitmap**  error is there .  let me know

Comment: Yes, I have an imagePath and this is an example of a path I get: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20170217-WA0001.jpg

Comment: I get this error: /BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20170217-WA0001.jpg: open failed:
     But I have this line in the manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: are you trying in API level >= 23 ?

Comment: Yes i'm using API=23

Comment: And the device you are using is above Lollipop ? , in case of yes, have you provided runtime permission ?